# How to generate RANDOM amount of a SINGLE character using java.util.Random?

Tags: java, for-loop, random, ascii

community.

I need help generating a random amount of a single character (the '*', to be more specific) via Java.

I need to generate 5 lines of asterisks (each ranging from 1-10 asterisks long). For example, it might look something like this:

```
***
*******
****
*********
***
```

Should I use the for loop to generate this code?

Here is what my (discombobulated) code looks like now:

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{

   String asterisk1 = "*";
   char character = '*';
   int ascii = (int) character;

   Random rand = new Random();
   char randomAsterisk = (char) ('*' + Math.random() * ('*' ));

   for (ascii = 1; ascii < 10; ascii ++)
   {
      System.out.println((char)character);
   }
}
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Are you asking how to generate a random number between 1 and 10, or are you asking how to create a string of length N with the same character repeated N times? The answer to both can easily be found by searching the web, so question downvoted for lack of research.

Comment: the latter - creating a string of length with the asterisk repeated N times.
I was scoping the interwebs for a few hours but could only find answers pertaining to random characters (and not a string of length). This is my first post, so I'll accept the downvote.

Comment: One step at a time.  Figure out how to generate a line of _n_  asterisks for some arbitrary variable _n_.  When you can do that, figure out how to do it 10 times.  When you can do that, figure out how to pick a random _n_ for each line.

Comment: You were searching the web for hours and could find how to repeat characters??? Try to Google: [`java repeat character`](https://www.google.com/search?q=java+repeat+character)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to print 5 lines of asterisks of 1 to 10 long,try something like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
   Random rand = new Random();
   for ( int j = 0; j < 5; ++j)
   {
      int num = rand.nextInt(10);
      for ( int i = 0; i <= num; ++i )
      {
         System.out.print('*');
      }
      System.out.println();
   }
}
```

Comment: Usagi, I really appreciate your time and your help! This is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Generate a random number and use a `for` loop to print the character equal to the amount of the random number. Another `for` loop can be used to print several lines of asterisks.

```
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom;

public class Main {
    public static void printChar(char c,
                                 int lower,
                                 int upper) {
        int n = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(lower, upper + 1);

        for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
            System.out.print(c);
        }

        System.out.println();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final int lines = 5;

        for (int i = 0; i < lines; ++i) {
            printChar('*', 1, 10);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why is `(10 - 1) +1`?

Comment: Thanks for explaining the upper and lower bound arguments - it's an interesting way of logic that's new to me (aside from what I am learning in calculus now).

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to do it:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    // Create a Random number generator
    Random rand = new Random();

    // Loop through all 10 lines
    int lineCount = 10;
    for (int lineIndex =0; lineIndex<lineCount;lineIndex++){
        // Generate a random amount of asterisks between one and 10 by
        // using the random number generater to generate a number less
        // than 10 (0 to 9) then adding one to that random number
        int asteriskCount = rand.nextInt(10)+1;

        // Print an asterisk asteriskCount times
        for (int asteriskIndex=0;asteriskIndex<asteriskCount;asteriskIndex++){
            System.out.print('*');
        }

        // Print a newline character (Which is like pressing enter)
        System.out.print('\n');
    }
}
```

Comment: Although I have not learned these lineIndex and lineCount concepts yet in class (since I'm a beginner), I just learned something new thanks to your comments. I appreciate it.